# MySQL exists subquery performs significantly worse in 8.0 than 5.7

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-8.0

I'm looking to upgrade my MySQL database from 5.7.33 to 8.0.28. I use it with a Laravel app that generates queries using a `whereHas` method that uses an exists subquery. However, I've noticed that performance has substantially reduced between the two versions - from ~5ms to 4s.

Here are the queries:

```sql
select * from `categories` where exists (select * from `jobs` inner join `category_job` on `jobs`.`id` = `category_job`.`job_id` where `categories`.`id` = `category_job`.`category_id`) order by `name` asc
```

What is interesting if that if I remove the exists subquery entirely, the query returns to a reasonable speed again - around the 5ms mark.

```sql
select * from `categories` order by `name` asc
```

What I'm trying to understand is **why** the performances changes so substantially between the two versions - if there is an error in my SQL that could be improved (or perhaps, changed in the framework to avoid the problem) - or this is simply a performance regression in MySQL that I'll have to live with.

I get that the first query is more work and going to be slower with the exists subquery, but I don't understand how simply upgrading MySQL has had thie effect.

---

When I run the query with EXPLAINS I get different results between 5.7 and 8.0 as well (note also that the databases have the same indexes):

5.7:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | categories |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 27 | 100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | category_job |  | ref | category_job_category_id_index,category_job_job_id_index | category_job_category_id_index | 8 | jobsnearme.categories.id | 35253 | 100.00 |  |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | jobs |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | jobsnearme.category_job.job_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

8.0:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | categories | NULL | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 30 | 100.00 | Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE |  | NULL | eq_ref | <auto_distinct_key> | <auto_distinct_key> | 8 | jobsnearme.categories.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | jobs | NULL | index | PRIMARY | jobs_company_id_index | 9 | NULL | 718220 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | category_job | NULL | ref | category_job_category_id_index,category_job_job_id_index | category_job_job_id_index | 8 | jobsnearme.jobs.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |

Here is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE category_job` from 8.0:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `category_job` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_job_category_id_index` (`category_id`),
  KEY `category_job_job_id_index` (`job_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_job_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_job_job_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1070585 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: why can't you just use `select * from categories where exists (select * from category_job where categories.id = category_job.category_id) order by name`? Also, do you have same indexes on both database?

Comment: It appears `jobs.id` and `category_job.job_id` are both `bigint(20) unsigned` on 5.7 and `bigint unsigned` on 8.0, curious but not something intentionally done. Identical dataset in both instances.

Comment: In V8 it seems to use a non-relevant key "jobs_company_id_index", which has 718220 rows. In V5 it uses "category_job_category_id_index" on 35253 rows. But to be honest, without playing a bit with these queries/databases, use `FORCE INDEX` here and there, I don't think I can tell why this happens. The query itself isn't super complex. Did you try the query that SalmanA suggested?

Comment: I just tried @SalmanA's query and it runs in 24ms which is much more reasonable - does that give any clues as to what's going on?

Comment: If I use the original query with FORCE INDEX then it also returns in 24ms - `select * from `categories`  where exists (select * from `jobs` inner join `category_job` force index (category_job_category_id_index) on `jobs`.`id` = `category_job`.`job_id` where `categories`.`id` = `category_job`.`category_id`) order by `name` asc`. So is this literally just a matter of MySQL 8 making bad index choices?

Comment: No, it doesn't give a clue, I was just curious. Ah, so it does indeed look like it has something to do with the execution plan. That's [a very esoteric topic](https://www.percona.com/blog/correcting-mysql-inaccurate-table-statistics-for-better-execution-plan/). I don't know enough about it. I just fiddle with things until they are performant. Not the best strategy, but trial and error is often the quickest.

Comment: It could be that the table statistics are wrong, due to the import. You could try [ANALYSE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) on the relevant tables to recalculate the statistics. I don't think it will help, but it is easy to do and if there's even a small change it will, why not try it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `semijoin=off` in the optimizer_switch and check the EXPLAIN result

```
SET optimizer_switch = 'semijoin=off';
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you for this suggestion! This made a huge difference and making the laravel queries comparable to 5.7 for me.

Answer (score -2):

A common inefficiency in a many-to-many table schema.

This would be faster:

```
CREATE TABLE `category_job` (
  `category_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `job_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (category_id, job_id),
  KEY (job_id, category_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```