# MySQL WHERE EXISTS subquery performance between 5.7 and 8.0

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have an `animals` table (~2.7m records) and a `breeds` table (~2.7m records) that have a one to many relationship (one animal can have multiple breeds). I'm trying to query all distinct breeds for a specific species. As I'm not a SQL expert, my initial thought was to go with a simple `SELECT DISTINCT breed ... JOIN`, but this query took about 10 seconds which seemed much longer than I'd expect. So I changed this to a `SELECT DISTINCT ... WHERE EXISTS` subquery and it executed in about 100ms in 5.7, which is much more reasonable. But now I'm migrating to MySQL 8 and this exact query takes anywhere from 10-30 seconds. Here are the table definitions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `animals` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `species` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` enum('Male','Female') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `animals_name_index` (`name`),
  KEY `animals_dob_index` (`dob`),
  KEY `animals_sex_index` (`sex`),
  KEY `animals_species_index` (`species`,`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2807152 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `animal_breeds` (
  `animal_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `breed` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique` (`animal_id`,`breed`),
  KEY `animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index` (`breed`,`animal_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `animal_breeds_animal_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`animal_id`) REFERENCES `animals` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is the query I'm running:

```sql
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT `breed` 
        FROM `animal_breeds`
    ) AS `subQuery`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT `breed`
        FROM `animal_breeds`
        INNER JOIN `animals` ON `animals`.`id` = `animal_breeds`.`animal_id`
        WHERE `animals`.`species` = 'Dog'AND `animal_breeds`.`breed` = `subQuery`.`breed`
    );
```

Here are the two `EXPLAIN` statements from 5.7 and 8.0

**MySQL 5.7**

284 rows in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 7775 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | animal_breeds | NULL | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | 1022 | allBreeds.breed | 348 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | animals | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index | PRIMARY | 4 | animal_breeds.animal_id | 1 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | animal_breeds | NULL | range | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | 1022 | NULL | 7775 | 100.00 | Using index for group-by |

**MySQL 8.0.27**

284 rows in set, 1 warning (27.92 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 7776 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <subquery3> | NULL | eq_ref | <auto_distinct_key> | <auto_distinct_key> | 1022 | allBreeds.breed | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 3 | MATERIALIZED | animals | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index | animals_species_index | 153 | const | 1390666 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 3 | MATERIALIZED | animal_breeds | NULL | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | 5 | animals.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | animal_breeds | NULL | range | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | 1022 | NULL | 7776 | 100.00 | Using index for group-by |

Lastly, both of these databases are using the base docker image with no changes to the configuration. Although the query still runs poorly on an VPS running MySQL 8 with some tweaked settings. I also read through [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72644205/mysql-exists-subquery-performs-significantly-worse-in-8-0-than-5-7) about someone having a similar problem but the comments/answer didn't seem to help in my case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is the execution plan for the `SELECT DISTINCT ... JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ab.breed
FROM animal_breeds ab
INNER JOIN animals a on a.id=ab.animal_id
WHERE a.species='Dog'
```

**MySQL 5.7**

284 rows in set (25.27 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index,id_species | animals_species_index | 153 | const | 1385271 | 100.00 | Using index; Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ab | NULL | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | 5 | a.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

**MySQL 8.0**

284 rows in set (29.45 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index,id_species | animals_species_index | 153 | const | 1390666 | 100.00 | Using index; Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ab | NULL | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique,animal_breeds_breed_animal_id_index | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | 5 | a.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

```sql
SELECT ab.breed
FROM animal_breeds ab
INNER JOIN animals a on a.id=ab.animal_id
WHERE a.species='Dog'
```

**MySQL 5.7**

2722722 rows in set (26.69 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index,id_species | animals_species_index | 153 | const | 1385271 | 100.00 | Using index |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ab | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | 5 | a.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |  |

**MySQL 8.0**

2722722 rows in set (32.49 sec)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,animals_species_index,id_species | animals_species_index | 153 | const | 1390666 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ab | NULL | ref | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | animal_breeds_animal_id_breed_unique | 5 | a.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

Comment: Why do you have all these subqueries? Isn't this the same as just `SELECT DISTINCT breed FROM animal_breeds JOIN animals ... WHERE ...`?

Comment: The subquery is much more performant. `SELECT DISTINCT breed JOIN animals` takes about 25 seconds on 5.7 and 45 seconds on 8.0. Maybe this is due to query cache size and other config settings?

Comment: The problem seems to be that 8.0 is materializing both subqueries before doing the `EXISTS` tests

Comment: Yeah that's what it seems like. Any way to force it to execute the EXISTS before materializing the subqueries?

Comment: The query cache was disabled by default in MySQL 5.6, deprecated in 5.7, and removed from the product in 8.0. If you are using default configuration settings, it should not be a factor in any of your tests.

Comment: @BillKarwin I see, thanks. Any insight into what this might be then? Seems like a pretty straightforward join/where exists and shouldn't be taking this long

Comment: I'd use the DISTINCT with JOIN solution you show in your second example. It seems to be using indexes effectively, so I can't explain why either version of MySQL is so slow. The default tuning settings of MySQL are rather low-profile, so you probably need to increase at least the buffer pool size. Other than that, I'd wonder if you are just using a server with poor performance power, or else you have other apps on the same server competing for resources.

Comment: It seems crazy but I'm just not seeing any improvement. The `animals` table is about 1.3G and the `breeds` table is about 300M (data + indexes). I don't have a big server by any means, but I feel like its 8G of memory (with a 5G buffer pool size) should be able to accommodate this on on mysql 8.0. That's more resources than we have allocated on our 5.7 machine but the 5.7 machine is able to perform this query pretty quickly

Comment: "one animal can have multiple breeds" -- There seem to be very few cases of such??

Comment: Yes and no. Biologically there are, of course, many mix-bred animals. Our software is currently used mostly for purebred animals but we are expanding it for mixed breeds. We've had requests for adding up to 5 associated breeds per animal. We also have a similar problem with an animal's color and the query associated with it. Some animals can have 3+ colors. At the moment I'm storing these values in cache and updating them a new breed or color is added -- and maybe that's just the way to go. But I feel like this query should not be taking 10 seconds, especially when it was so quick on mysql 5.7

Answer (score 2):

Filtering `animals` before joining it to `breeds` will improve performance (10x faster in some cases):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ab.breed
FROM    animal_breeds ab
WHERE   ab.animal_id IN (
                     SELECT a.id
                     FROM animals a
                     WHERE a.species = 'Dog');
```

Comment: This query is extremely slow as well (~8 seconds). I still cannot figure out why mysql 5.7 performs so much better with the exact table structures, data, and queries.

Comment: @Jeff I tested this query with the same scenario you mentioned in the question and the improvement was more than 10x faster. Do you have any additional details to share related to your environment and scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write query without inner join and start with a table that contains columns from where conditions. Here is the one of possible variants:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ab.breed
FROM animals a
LEFT JOIN animal_breeds ab on a.id = ab.animal_id
WHERE a.species = 'Dog'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing. The `animals` table is indeed a bit larger than what I've described in my question (hence the 1.3 GB size). It still performs poorly with only the columns that are required for the join.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

- Change the table name `animals` to `pets`.  (I think of "Fido" as a pet and "dog" as an animal.  Because of this, it took me a long time to figure out the schema.)
- Move `species` to the other table, now called`pet_species`.  Though I cannot imagine a "cat" breed being called "retriever", it does make sense that (species, breed) is a hierarchical pair of terms.
- Another confusion:  Technically speaking a "dog" is "Canis familiaris", which is [technically] two terms 'genus' and 'species'.

Moving species to the other table will lead to some changes to the queries.  You *could* have it in both tables, though DB purists say that redundant information is a "no-no".  I have not thought of a compromise between the two stands.